# adding barcode in sql server 2012 report

Tags: report, barcode

I am currently having a report created in SQL Server 2008 where we are generating the Barcode as custom report item, when I tried the same I found that this is not supported in SQL server 2012 reporting services.

Kindly suggest how can I add a Barcode as a custom report item in SQL server 2012 reporting services

Thanks in advance.

Rakesh

Comment: Cant you just use barcode font and then display them as such?

Comment: What type of bar code are you trying to display on the report?